# Django Custom Sequence Format

Tags: python, django, sequence

I would like to create a custom sequence such as `PO-0001` for a Purchase Order, `SO-0001` for a Sales Order, etc.

I have tried something like this:

```
class Requisitions(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Number')
    transDate = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date')
    businessUnit = models.ForeignKey(BusinessUnit, verbose_name='Unit')
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, verbose_name='Division')
    remarks = models.TextField
    status = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Status')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        letter = 'REQ-'
        lastNumber = 1
        self.number = '%s%03d'(letter,lastNumber)

        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I got an error in the admin page when I save a new record:

```
'str' object is not callable
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/admin/procurement/requisitions/add/
 Django Version: 1.11.3
 Exception Type: TypeError
 Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I solve that error?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you **must not** use `self.__class__` as the first argument to `super`. This will cause an infinite loop if you ever subclass this model. Use the class name explicitly, or upgrade to Python 3 where you don't need to pass anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omitted to include the string format (`%`) operator. Change the following line:

```
self.number = '%s%03d'(letter,lastNumber)
```

to

```
self.number = '%s%03d' % (letter,lastNumber)
```

Or even better, use the more modern `.format()` function:

```
self.number = '{0}{1:03d}'.format(letter, lastNumber)
```